# React Native - Adding logic to Stack Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following Stack Navigation:

```
const WelcomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    UpdateProfileScreen: {
        screen: UpdateProfileScreen,
    },
    SelectProfileScreen: {
        screen: SelectProfileScreen,
    },
    PresentationModal: {
        screen: PresentationModal,
    }
}, {
    initialRouteName: 'UpdateProfileScreen',
    headerMode: 'none'
})
```

When a user is new, I show "UpdateProfileScreen" first, then I move to "SelectProfileSecreen" and then  "PresentationModal".

If for some reason after "UpdateProfileScreen" user closes the app, next time they log in I will show "SelectProfileSecreen" and "PresentationModal". If they complete data, next time, they will only see the "PresentationModal"

Since I have set "UpdateProfileScreen" as initialRoute, it will always load first, even if it does not show.

So I was wondering if programatically I could change the initialRoute and/or if I do:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("WelcomeStack")
```

I can add some logic in the same stack to handle the page to show?

Comment: It looks like you would use a `createSwitchNavigator`:https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/switch-navigator/

Comment: @B.Mohammad yes I am using createSwitchNavigator since I have other stacks, but how do I apply it for this case?

Comment: Just explore react navigation library , you will find all there , and start using react navigation 5.0.

Comment: You could set a component where you check you logic and then redirect to appropriate screen.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is using `SwitchNavigator(RouteConfigs, SwitchNavigatorConfig)` you can simply create it with  `createSwitchNavigator` as it controls all the switching of navigators used mainly for authentication flow in most react native apps.

With that said, for your case i think its the most suitable way to achieve the desired behavior.

Please be careful if publishing an app using something along the lines of :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate("WelcomeStack")
```

as it can be a serious security vulnerability

docs: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/switch-navigator/

snack example: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using SwitchNavigator since I have other stacks but not sure how to use it for this case. Also can you explain me more about the security vulnerability please?

Comment: Well since it is a simple boolean variable it could be accessed by anyone who has Apk Extractor and a JAVA de-compiler will be able to access it.

Did you check out https://reactnavigation.org/docs/1.x/auth-flow/? if you still want me to post a small program afterwards i will.

Comment: Thanks, I will review the code in detail. But if someone decompiles the app, will it not be the same for any method I use?

Comment: Well, firstly using the switch navigator will make it virtually impossible for one stack to see another so that will improve security. But my personal opinion is that the awesome work from the people who developed react native make sure that variables are nested and referenced with links adding additional security. not saying that it is impossible just saying that it will take a good chunk of time to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem here how i resolved it:
Added `SwitchNavigator` like so:

```js
let Navigation = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoading,
    LoginNavigator: LoginNavigator,
    HomeNavTab: tabNavigator,
    LoggedInChose: LoggedInChose
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "AuthLoading"
  }
);
```

The `AuthLoading` stack is the first to load and decides where the app go next:

```js
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class AuthLoading extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkUserSession();
  }


  checkUserSession = () => {
    const userData = this.props.userData;

    if (userData) {
      const residencesNumber = userData.nbreResidences;
      if (residencesNumber == 1) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeNavTab");
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate("LoggedInChose");
      }
    } else {
      this.props.navigation.navigate("LoginNavigator");
    }
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      null
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    userData: state.userData
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthLoading);
```

Maybe you get an idea from this.